# Android value of counter

Tags: android, counter

how can i get the value of a counter counting down?

I've been trying with sg like this, but it has a problem with the type:

```
counter = new MyCount(10000,1000);
                  String secs;
                  secs=counter.toString();
                  if (started == false)
                  {
                      counter.start();
                      started = true;
                     switch (secs) {
                      case 8000: 
                            tv3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            break;
                      case 3000: 
                            tv3.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                            break;

                     }

                  }
```

Update:

MyCount is declared as `MyCount counter;`

I have also this code:

```
`public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

        }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
         tv  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        tv.setText("Time is up!");
    }`
```

I put the switch part here:

```
@Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        tv.setText("" + millisUntilFinished/1000);
         switch (millisUntilFinished) {  //here is the problem
            case 8000:
                tv3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 3000:
                tv3.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                break;
            }
    }
```

It had a problem with the switch parameter: "*Cannot switch on a value of type long. Only convertible int values or enum constants are permitted*"

That is way I have changed that line to `switch ((int)millisUntilFinished/1000) {` and changed to case lines to `case 8:` and `case 3:`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is `MyCount`, but I see the error. Variable `secs` has type `String`, but you are trying compare it with the integers (3000, 8000). You can't use `String` variables in the `switch` block. You need use there integer variable or, if counter has String type, use something like this code instead of the `switch` block:

```
if ("8000".equals(secs)) {
    tv3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
} else if ("3000".equals(secs)) {
    tv3.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

**Upd:** If you use subclass of the [CountDownTimer](http://d.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html), you need to define [`onTick()`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#onTick%28long%29) callback in the `MyCount` class, like this:

```
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    switch (millisUntilFinished) {
    case 8000:
        ...
        break;
    case 3000:
        ...
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, what is MyCount()?

And, to add to Sergey's answer:

You 'start' the counter, but you never do anything else with it (that we can see)  How does the counter get updated?